# How to fade out a Bitmap with gtkmm?

Tags: cairo, gtkmm

I use

```
Glib::RefPtr<Gdk::Pixbuf> image = Gdk::Pixbuf::create_from_file(sBitmapName);
Gdk::Cairo::set_source_pixbuf(cr, image, x, y);
```

to load and display a bitmap in a cairo context.

Is it possible to manipulate the pixels in the pixbuf once it is loaded?
I would like to fade out this image by decreasing the the alpha value of each pixel.

Or is there another possibility to fade out a pixmap?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution i found:

with `guchar *Gdk::Pixbuf::get_pixels()` you get access to the pixels of the image. Any changes you make in this array are visible the next time the image is drawn:

```
int iW = m_image->get_width();
int iH = m_image->get_height();
guchar * pPixels = m_image->get_pixels();
int iNChannels = m_image->get_n_channels();
if (iNChannels == 4) {
    for (int iY = 0; iY < iH; iY++) {
        for (int iX = 0; iX < iW; iX++) {
            int iOffset = iY*m_image->get_rowstride() + iX*iNChannels;
            pPixels[iOffset+3] *= dRatio;
        }
    }
}
```

This fragment multiplies the alpha value of each pixel with real number thus changing the transparency. Repeatedly applying this leads to a fade-out effect